# Creating ClickOnce Applications for Others to Deploy

Tags: msbuild, clickonce

I have a WPF application and I'm creating a ClickOnce deployment from my continuous integration server (TeamCity) with a MSBuild command.

Then I would like to give the deployment files to others, so they can modify the  URL in the .application file by their own server address where they want to host the files.

The problem is that the .application file cannot be simply modified like this. It has to be resigned...

Is there a simple way to do what I need without resigning the .application file ?

I found [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384248.aspx) and [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384246.aspx) but I'm not using Mage.exe for my deployment. And What should I do after the deployment MSBuild command to do what I need ?

My parameters :

```
/P:Configuration=Release /P:Platform="x86" /P:DeployTarget="Publish" /P:SupportUrl="http://www.company.com" /P:ErrorReportUrl="http://www.company.com" /P:PublisherName="company" /P:ProductName="Product name" /P:TrustUrlParameters="true" /P:UpdateMode="Foreground"/P:PublishUrl="http://localhost/Installer/" /P:UseManifestForTrust="true" /P:MapFileExtensions="true" /P:PublishDir="../../Installer/" /P:ApplicationVersion=%Version%
```

The application should be able to be updated.

Comment: The step by step tutorial correctly explains it. You sign the application manifest, but not the deployment manifest. The customer changes the url and then signs with `mage.exe -Sign WindowsFormsApp1.application -CertFile MyCert.pfx`

Comment: Ok, it didn't work at first, using MageUI.exe, I had to reselect the .manifest file before saving the modification on the .application file, I don't know why... So there is absolutly no way to modify the URL without resigning the .application file, right ? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: And when I install the application, the Publisher is set to "Unknown Publisher", it does't take my certificate. And if I open the .manifest file with MageUI.exe, "Use Application Manifest for Trust Information" is not checked. ( But I used "/P:UseManifestForTrust="true" )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the `deploymentProvider` element; that would allow you to deploy a signed ClickOnce from multiple locations, i.e. multiple environments or multiple organisations in your case.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384243.aspx

> Starting with the .NET Framework 3.5, you no longer have to specify a deploymentProvider in your deployment manifest in order to deploy a ClickOnce application for both online and offline usage. This supports the scenario where you need to package and sign the deployment yourself, but allow other companies to deploy the application over their networks.

Comment: Thx, but where will it check for update then ? And how can I remove it modifying my MsBuild command ? I tried to remove the "/P:PublishUrl" parameter but it replaced the deployment provider by a local path...

Comment: @Gab it should check for updates from the same location it was installed from. I don't know if you can remove it with MSBuild property, I used to do it while resigning after config transformation, but I wrote a custom task and did it programmatically.

Comment: @Gab I think it might be `PublishUrl`, open up your .csproj in notepad and check description at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165431.aspx

Comment: Ok thank you. So all I have to do is find a way to drop the DeploymentProvider and everything should works like I need ? Only host a publish.htm page with an "install" button that point the the ".application" file ?

Comment: @Gab that's the idea, that's how you deploy to test and prod environments without changing urls. Although you loose some security omitting it from a prod deployment.

Comment: Ok thanks again it seems to works ! Still have to try to auto-update the application